# Ubuntu Struggling to run Python Script on Startup

Tags: command-line, python

I'm trying to run two scripts in a python project on startup in Ubuntu but it keeps having issues.
I have a Python project like the following:

- pycharm

  - venv
  - date.txt
  - globalfunctions.py
  - internet.txt
  - internetdate.txt
  - internettimelog.txt
  - internettracker.py
  - poweroutages.txt
  - poweroutagetracker.py
  - timelog.txt

The project path is /home/connor/Documents/Pycharm, with the IDE being a virtual environment of Python 3.8.10

And the two files I am trying to run are the internettracker.py and poweroutagetracker.py. The two codes are the following:

internettracker.py

```py
import requests
import time
import globalfunctions as gf

url = "http://www.kite.com"
timeout = 5


def ping_internet():
    try:
        request = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
        return True
    except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as exception:
        return False


gf.log_today(additional="internet")

while True:

    internet_connected = ping_internet()

    if internet_connected:
        datestring, timenumber = gf.get_log(additional="internet")
        curtime, today = gf.get_today()

        if abs(curtime - timenumber) > 35:
            gf.report_data("internet.txt", "Internet outage from [" + datestring + "] to [" + str(today) + "]")
            print("Internet Outage Detected")

        gf.log_today(additional="internet")
        time.sleep(30)
    else:
        time.sleep(15)
```

poweroutagetracker.py

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime
import globalfunctions as gf

while True:
    datestring, timenumber = gf.get_log()
    curtime, today = gf.get_today()

    if abs(curtime - timenumber) > 5:
        gf.report_data("poweroutages.txt", "Power outage from [" + datestring + "] to [" + str(today) + "]")
        print("Power Outage Detected")


    time.sleep(5)
    gf.log_today()
```

Supporting file with functions
globalfunctions.py

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime

def get_today():
    return time.time(), datetime.today()

def log_today(additional=""):
    curtime, today = get_today()

    datefile = open(additional+"date.txt", "w")
    datefile.write(str(today))
    datefile.close()

    timefile = open(additional+"timelog.txt", "w")
    timefile.write(str(curtime))
    timefile.close()

def get_log(additional=""):
    datefile = open(additional+"date.txt", "r")
    datestring = datefile.readline()

    timefile = open(additional+"timelog.txt", "r")
    timenumber = float(timefile.readline())

    return datestring, timenumber

def report_data(filename, text):
    curtime, today = get_today()
    outfile = open(filename, "a+")
    outfile.write(str(today) + " | " + text + "\n")
    outfile.close()
```

I tried following the instructions from [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416137/how-can-i-run-a-script-on-startup-on-ubuntu-server-17-10) but it does not seem to be working.
I made a .service with the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Python Internet Watcher

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/connor/Documents/Pycharm
ExecStart=./internettracker.py


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This file was moved into /lib/systemd/system/ and so far I saw nothing being ran on startup.

Comment: Is there any error reported in the Log? Please append to post.

Comment: I see "print" statements in your scripts. Since systemd runs headless, those won't be printed to the screen. Consider writing your output to a file instead, then use any of several tools to read that output once you are logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem. I found out you can activate the virtual environment for the project and then start the program inside of the virtual environment.

In the project, the venv can by activated via [project_path]/venv/bin/python

Here are the changes for the solution:

```
[Unit]
Description=Python Internet Watcher
After=network-online.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/connor/Documents/Pycharm
ExecStart=/home/connor/Documents/Pycharm/venv/bin/python internettracker.py start
Restart=always
RestartSec=15s
KillMode=process
TimeoutSec=infinity
User=connor
Group=connor

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

command-line
python

Comment: The working directory of a .service is the same as the system root directory `/` in which the service manager started, and `~` for user .service units.